# Doesn't the date matter when deciding which post is the duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I've seen a post which was flagged as duplicate. Then I checked the other post. The post which was flagged was posted in 2008, other was posted in 2010. I've flagged this situation as there was something I thought was wrong. This is what they said:

[image]

What actually matters? Can I ask a question now and make another post flagged as duplicate?

Answer (score 10):

What matters is that the better question or question with better answers is left open and other versions of the question closed as a duplicate of it - regardless of when the questions were posted.

We want to be *the* place to go for *the* best answers on the internet. To achieve this we want to keep open the best questions or, more accurately, the questions that provoke the best answers.

In the normal case a new question will be quite quickly closed as a duplicate of the older one, simply because the older one has been around longer and has had more chance to attract good answers. Occasionally a duplicate slips through and attracts good answers. In that case we can, and do, close the older one as a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But if you check these two questions and answers, the old one is more upvoted and favourited, also has the answers with more upvotes. Anyway, if you want to close the old questions, then you need to change the word. Because "duplicate" is not the right word. Duplicate: `A copy of an original`, `Exactly like something else, especially through having been copied` and original: `The earliest form of something, from which copies may be made`, in case you needed copy, too: `A thing made to be similar or identical to another` (taken from Oxford dictionary)

Comment: No wonder questions surrounding Jon Skeet will never be duplicates... http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9277/289845

Comment: @farukdgn There are multiple definitions of the term "duplicate". You're just cherry-picking those that you like. *Some* of the definitions do not imply that an *original* was *copied*.

Comment: @Louis Can you show me the one which implies that `something that is worse than another` or anything that fits to the situation? I understand they want to make the site better but it would be unpleasant for me if someone flagged my question as `duplicate` if I was the original asker. Why can't there be something like `there is a better answer here` flag? NOTE: If you read the description in the duplicate information, it says "This question has been asked **before** and **already** has an answer". Oh, never mind, it seems like you found other meanings for them, too.